# Communicating with my system admin: SSL for Apache httpd, and for Tomcat

Tags: ssl, tomcat

I'm at the mercy of a sys admin who handles middleware config for an application I'm working on.  Long story short I asked for SSL to be enabled for the application.

The app is split up between a PHP layer being served from Apache httpd, and a set of REST services in Java, being served by Tomcat 8.5 (standalone) on port 8443.

After the sys admin told me "your SSL is fully configured", I hit the base app at:

```
https://www.example.com/myapp/
```

Comes up fine, no SSL warnings and green padlock.  However:

```
https://www.example.com:8443/myRestAPI/
```

still gives a warning on SSL.  So, is there a hint of some sort or guidance, link to a good how-to, or anything I can share with this person to get her some help to understand how to get this SSL working on that Tomcat/port ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat SSL configuration is done in the `server.xml` The connector needs to be configured like this:

```
<Connector port="8443"
   protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
   secure="true"
   scheme="https"
   SSLEnabled="true"
   SSLCertificateFile="/path/to/ocsp-cert.crt"
   SSLCertificateKeyFile="/path/to/ocsp-cert.key"
   SSLCACertificateFile="/path/to/ca.pem"
   SSLVerifyClient="require"
   SSLVerifyDepth="10"
   clientAuth="true"/>
```

[Tomcat SSL documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Configuring_OCSP_Connector)

Another option would be to configure the Apache httpd as a reverse proxy in front of the Tomcat.

Comment: Yes, to this: "Another option would be to configure the Apache httpd as a reverse proxy in front of the Tomcat." The sysadmin might have already done that. Hopefully they did as that is more advisable. Its easier to maintain ongoing support for SSL changes if it can be configured in one place, at the reverse proxy. More control too.